# how to add annotation to ybar pgfplots with symbolic x coords

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates, bar-chart

I would like to add an annotation, or better, an arrow to a particular ybar in a plot, but I am struggling with the symbolic x data. I've used \pgfplotsinvokeforeach to read in variable data, and so haven't explicitly defined the x values. Whenever I try to specify the coordinates with eg \node[coordinate,pin=right:{Tasmania entry to NEM}] at (axis cs:2004/5,190) {}; I get an error (not a floating point value), so I have had to use the numeric value of 0 which places my comment roughly in the right place.
The question is - how to specify the correct node so that it will be placed at the top of the desired bar? The working example is below - but I would like to place the comment at the top and left of the 2005/6 y bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    select row/.style={
        x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}
    }
}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1999/00,167.1
2000/1,172.5
2001/2,175
2002/3,179.3
2003/4,184.4
2004/5,188
2005/6,201.7
2006/7,208.3
2007/8,210.2
2008/9,210.5
2009/10,209.8
2010/11,207.5
2011/12,203.4
2012/13,198.2
%2013/14(YTD),97
}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}[
    %title=Australia's Primary Energy Consumption by sector - 2012,
        ybar, bar shift=0pt,
        enlarge y limits=0.1,
        %xmin=0,
        xtick={0,...,13},
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width=3mm, 
        width=12cm, height=9cm, 
        xlabel={year},
    ylabel={TWh},
        x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,rotate=45, anchor=east},
         nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,13}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, select row=#1] {\datatable};
}
\node[coordinate,pin=right:{Tasmania entry to NEM}] at (axis cs:0,190) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I presume the '5' (axis cs:5,190) refers to the 6th bar, so I could move the pin by changing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one possible solution. Here a pin is added so that the label for bar is clearly pointed.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
select row/.style={
    x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}
}
}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1999/00,167.1
2000/1,172.5
2001/2,175
2002/3,179.3
2003/4,184.4
2004/5,188
2005/6,201.7
2006/7,208.3
2007/8,210.2
2008/9,210.5
2009/10,209.8
2010/11,207.5
2011/12,203.4
2012/13,198.2
%2013/14(YTD),97
}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}[
    %title=Australia's Primary Energy Consumption by sector - 2012,
    ybar, bar shift=0pt,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    %xmin=0,
    xtick={0,...,13},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
    ymajorgrids = true,
    bar width=3mm, 
    width=12cm, height=9cm, 
    xlabel={year},
    ylabel={TWh},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,rotate=45, anchor=east},
     nodes near coords align={horizontal},
   ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,13}{
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, select row=#1] {\datatable};
}
\node[pin={[pin distance=1cm,pin edge={<-,>=stealth'},shift={(-1.2cm,0.5cm)}]
Tasmania entry to NEM}] at (axis cs:5,190) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```