# Plot bar chart from csv with different styles depending on row in csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, csv, axis, pattern

I try to plot the content of a csv file in a bar chart, where depending on the row the bar should have a different style. This is what I came up with so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    ;res
    a;1
    b;2
    c;3
    d;4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}
         \center
         \begin{tikzpicture}
             \pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}\datatable
             \begin{axis}[xticklabels from table = {\datatable}{0}, xtick=data]
                 \addplot [ybar,draw = blue,fill=blue!50] table 
                          [x expr=\coordindex, 
                           col sep=semicolon,
                           restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{0:1},         
                           y={res}] {\datatable};
                 \addplot [ybar,draw = blue,
                           fill=blue!50, postaction={
                           pattern=north east lines
                 }] table [x expr=\coordindex,
                           col sep=semicolon, 
                           y={res},
                           restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{2:3}] {data.csv};
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My problem is that in this case the labels on the x axis are missing for the bars with patterns. Does anyone know, how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you could e.g. use [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165833/121799). The question is on some additional feature, but as far as I can see the code manages to add the x labels and does the individual styles somewhat more systematically. You could add your styles either to the loop or to the cycle list.

Comment: `xtick=data` means "add xticks at the data points from *the first* `\addplot`". In the question @marmot links to the tick positions are specified with `xtick={0,...,3}` instead of `xtick=data`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is true but not the reason why I was linking the answer. Rather, I was linking it because of `select row`, which is IMHO slightly more elegant. All one has to do is to use that loop and adjust it to the needs.

Comment: @marmot Sure, but the specific question here was about why the xticklabels were gone, so I thought I'd point out exactly what caused that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All relevant information is already contained in [Torbjørn T.'s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459345/plot-bar-chart-from-csv-with-different-styles-depending-on-row-in-csv#comment1155118_459345) and I will be happy to remove this post if Torbjørn adds his answer. All I did is to retrieve the number of rows from the table and add this information at the appropriated place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    ;res
    a;1
    b;2
    c;3
    d;4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
             \pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}\datatable
             \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
             \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
             \typeout{\rownum}
             \begin{axis}[xticklabels from table = {\datatable}{0}, 
             xtick={0,...,\rownum}]
                 \addplot [ybar,draw = blue,fill=blue!50] table 
                          [x expr=\coordindex, 
                           col sep=semicolon,
                           restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{0:1},         
                           y={res}] {\datatable};
                 \addplot [ybar,draw = blue,
                           fill=blue!50, postaction={
                           pattern=north east lines
                 }] table [x expr=\coordindex,
                           col sep=semicolon, 
                           y={res},
                           restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{2:3}] {data.csv};
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]